# JavaFx optional parameters for controller class in start method when it is loaded into the FXML

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

with the ScheneBuilder I defined the controller class of my fxml, the code genereted inside my AnchorPane tag is:

```
fx:controller="demo.SplashController"
```

now I would like if I had args in the main, to load a new version of the controller, using the appropriate construct. I try this code in the Application.start:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("page.fxml"));
PageController controller;
if(!dir.equals("")){ //attribute coming from args
  controller = new PageController(dir);
}else{
  controller = new PageController();  
}
loader.setController(controller);
AnchorPane root = loader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(root,480,414);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

but using this code a conflict appears because I have already defined the controller in my project with FXML code, to solve it would be enough to remove the segment in the FXML code but I would not do it because leaving the code in the fxml allows me to access some good features of the SceneBuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way pass parameters to the controller's constructor **and** specify the controller's class in the fxml is to use a controller factory:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("page.fxml"));
loader.setControllerFactory(cl -> dir.isEmpty() ? new PageController() : new PageController(dir));
AnchorPane root = loader.load();
```

---

Another option would be to create a method in the controller class that allows you to pass the info after loading and does the initialisation:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("page.fxml"));
AnchorPane root = loader.load();
PageController controller = loader.getController();
controller.setDir(dir);
```

Note that the method call happens after the `initialize` method is run assuming there is one.