# Scene Builder doesn't open when properties are defined in FXML file

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a **FXML file** that I usually edit with **SceneBuilder**.

Having the need to keep a reference to the controller of the file so that I can access it later, I am saving the controller reference in a **properties** tag of the FXML.

The problem is that event though this works as I expected in the application, I cannot edit the FXML in SceneBuilder afterwards.
This means that every time I want to edit the UI in SceneBuilder, I have to delete the **properties** tag temporarily.

I already searched a lot in the internet for answers but with no success.
The most similar question I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339053/javafx-optional-parameters-for-controller-class-in-start-method-when-it-is-loade) but it doesn't answer to mine.

**My FXML file** is organized as shown below:

```
<AnchorPane minWidth="300.0" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <properties>
      <!-- store controller at key "foo" in properties map -->
      <foo><fx:reference source="controller" /></foo> 
   </properties>
   <children>
      <!-- children nodes here -->
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**It's important to note that no errors are shown when I try to open the file in SceneBuilder.**

Comment: Why don't you use a controller in "one line" like this:
<AnchorPane ........ fx:controller="controller">

Comment: @Anatoly Because I am passing values to the controller in the constructor. So, I first instantiate the controller with the values I want to use and then set the controller in my FXML Loader.

Comment: Are you sure SceneBuilder is not already "running?"  I have this issue on my work laptop; SceneBuilder does not properly close and needs to be killed in Task Manager every time (the window will close, but the task keeps running). If it's still running in the background, trying to run it again will only start a new invisible task of SB; it won't actually open. Worth checking.

Comment: I try to use your properties in my fxml. You right SceneBuilder doesn't open and Intellj asks me about "foo". I think you use right way write properties for xml but SceneBulder doesn't understand this format in fxml

Comment: @Zephyr I even restarted my pc but the problem is really because of the properties tag in the fxml.

Comment: @Anatoly Yes, the fxml works as I expect, the problem is really that SceneBuilder is not able to interpret it.

Comment: Ok. Look here "https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#property_setter_elements" about properties. Your way a little bit other than specification.